# Virtualisation Classification

Tags: virtualization

I have been reading virtualisation where i came across many types of virtualisation technique
Now i am confused about the types 
Here is my understanding of classifying virtualisation

> 1. Type 1(bare metal virtualisation)
>
>    1.1  Full virtualisation
>
>    1.2  para virtualisation
>
>    1.3  hardware assisted virtualisation
> 2. Type 2(host based virtualisation)

Am i correct??

I have searched internet but was not able to find satisfactory answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualization is a very broad term. There can be many components in IT world which can be virtualized. Most common types of virtualization are:

- OS Virtualization
- Application Virtualization
- Network Virtualization
- Hardware Virtualization
- Storage Virtualization

The terms you have mentioned (*Type 1 and Type 2*) are type of **Hypervisors**. Hypervisor can be thought of as an intermediate entity between a physical machine and virtual machine. Simply put hypervisor is the Virtualization enabler.

Hypervisor can virtualize physical resources using different techniques:

1. It can be done by making hypervisor part of Kernel which is called
   *Full virtualization*
2. Modifying the guest OS which can leverage hypervisor to intercept the calls made by VM to the physical resources. This is called *paravirtualization*.
3. Hardware itself can be modified like AMD-V or Inter VT-x processors to enable virtualization. In such case it is *hardware assisted virtualization*.

I hope it clarifies your doubt.